# My bank account changed country and IBAN during the year: which address and IBAN should I use in Turbotax, when filing for my US taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, international, turbotax, brexit

I have a bank account with [Revolut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolut). As a result of Brexit, [Revolut moved my bank account from Revolut UK to Revolut European entity in Lithuania (“Revolut Payments UAB”)](https://blog.revolut.com/transferring-our-lithuanian-customers-before-brexit/) on Nov. 6, 2020, and changed my bank account's IBAN accordingly.

In Turbotax, when filing for my US taxes as a US lawful permanent resident, which address and IBAN (= account number) when mentioning this "Foreign Financial Account"? The UK or the Lithuania one?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following some [Reddit advice](https://redd.it/nd99ti), I entered 2  "Foreign Financial Accounts" in Turbotax:

- 1  "Foreign Financial Account" for the Revolut UK account, which I marked as closed  in 2020. (institution name "Revolut Ltd.")
- 1  "Foreign Financial Account" for the Revolut Lithuania account, which I marked as opened in 2020. (institution name "Revolut Payments UAB")

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]